# How to stop sounds from playing when I close Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I was working on my android app with flutter and it has a bug right now where when the app is in the background, it still plays a sound. The idea of the app is to play a bell sound when you shake your phone. It also likes to slow down the phone when it is in the background as well. Here is the code for my home page. (the code might not be the best, this is my first app)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:bell/ad_state.dart';
import 'package:bell/globals.dart' as globals;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home>{
  bool isBackground;
  BannerAd banner;

  Future<AudioPlayer> playLocalAsset() async {
    AudioCache cache = new AudioCache();
    return await cache.play(globals.playerBellSound);
  }

  Future<AudioPlayer> shakeBell() async {
    AudioCache cache1 = new AudioCache();
    return await cache1.play(globals.shakeBellSound);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      if (event.x > 5.0 || event.x < -5.0) {
        shakeBell();
      }
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    adState.initialization.then((status) {
      setState(() {
        banner = BannerAd(
          adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
          size: AdSize.banner,
          request: AdRequest(),
          listener: adState.adListener,
        );
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    banner.load();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings');
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text("Any Bell"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/ocean.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    playLocalAsset();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.notifications,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 70,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: AdWidget(ad: banner),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return an `AudioPlayer` from `AudioCache.play()`

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = await cache.play('your file name');
```

Call `AudioPlayer.stop` in `dispose`

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but it didn't work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this by knowing in which state your App is.**

Here's the Code!

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class soundBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  const soundBoard({super.key});

  @override
  State<soundBoard> createState() => _soundBoardState();
}
// Step 1: Add with WidgetsBindingObserver To your Stateful Widget.
class _soundBoardState extends State<soundBoard> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final audioplayer = AudioPlayer();

  bool isPlaying = false;
  /* Step 4: Add this method. It will stop the audio from playing
  as soon as you close the app*/
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      if (AppLifecycleState.paused == state) {
        audioplayer.pause();
      }
    });
  }

  // Step 2: Create init State and add the line given under super.initState()
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  // Step 3: Create dispose method and add the line given under super.dispose()
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /* Step 5: Extra tip: Add the onWillPopScope method. If you are playing an 
    audio and you navigate to any other screen then the audio will stop.
    */
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          audioplayer.stop();
          return true;
        },
        child: Scaffold());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

place this below code on parent `StatefulWidget` class that is MaterialApp is residing

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      if (AppLifecycleState.detached == state) {
        player.stop();
      }
    });
  }
```

or

place the MaterialApp inside a `StatefulWidget` and place the below code on it

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      if (AppLifecycleState.detached == state) {
        player.stop();
      }
    });
  }
```